# How the California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA) impacts a non-Californian business?

Tags: privacy, california

January 1, 2020, the California Consumer Privacy Act (CCPA) goes into effect.

The CCPA applies to any business anywhere in the U.S. or the world that does business in the state of California. 
Could you please explain what does the term “in the state” mean in this context?

How will this impact non-California and non-US companies that are selling to consumers from California traveling and shopping outside of the US?

Comment: I actually found this information: "The phrase “does business in California” is not defined in the CCPA. Instead, one may assume that the requirement is modified by reference to the definition of “consumer” - a natural person who is a California resident - and therefore applies to any business, whether or not geographically located in California, that collects and/or sells the personal information of California residents." https://iapp.org/news/a/top-five-operational-impacts-of-cacpa-part-1-determining-if-youre-a-business-collecting-or-selling-consumers-personal-information/

Comment: Should non-US B2C companies generally assume some customers are Californian residents?

Comment: https://www.varonis.com/blog/california-consumer-privacy-act-ccpa/